# Slight modification to my jquery animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Here's the JsFiddle of my animation: http://jsfiddle.net/cCAPk/

If you look at it, you can see that when the div goes back to his original position, the black square is empty for a couple of sec. I dont want that to happen. If you add the overflow:hidden in the css, you can see clearlly where the div ends and when it start over.

How can I fix that?

And also I don't think I have the best way of calculating when the animation starts over..

Any help?

Here's the JS:

```
function loop2() {
  var lenght = $('#digit8').html().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, "").length;
  var top = $('#digit8').css("top");
  var max = "-" + (lenght -1) * 45 + "px";

   $('#digit8').animate({
      top: "-=45"
   }, 300, function() {

    if(top == max ){
        $('#digit8').css("top","45px");    
    }
});
}

 for (i=0; i<5; i++)
 {
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*9);              
  $("#digit8").append(number+" ");
}

setInterval("loop2()",600);​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/cCAPk/2/

I changed the generator to create elements at not text to allow easier removal. The loop shifts the wrapper 45px up and on callback removes the first element and puts it at the end (reshifting the wrapper down 45px to account).

A less DOM manipulation intensive solution would be to not use the callback: http://jsfiddle.net/cCAPk/3/

This has one issue that I attempted to address with the first solution: the animation between the last and first element is not the same as the others (the last element can not be seen when shifting the div back up).